# Cellular Automata Markov for forecast LULC in R software

Tags: raster, r, land-use, cellular-automata

I would like to forecast land use changes by implementing the Cellular Automata (CA) Markov Chain models in R software. 
I have the classified LULC maps from 3 times periods (1992,2003,2014), and also the Markov transition probabilities matrices. However, I  was not able to find any implementation in R that project land use using the CA Markov chain. I would like to predict for 2025.

Does anyone know if is any implementation in R for projecting LULC, similar to the one implemented in IDRISI with the module (CA-Markov)?

Or anyone knows a way of predict LULC in R using the CA-Markov?

Comment: Did you find the answer of your problem. I am having problems in the same subject

Comment: have you checked The markovchain Package: A Package for Easily
Handling Discrete Markov Chains in R? the documentations has some examples that could be applied to LUCC. have a look at the documentation here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/markovchain/vignettes/an_introduction_to_markovchain_package.pdf